# Error: Cannot find module '@babel/code-frame'

Tags: nextjs

Estoy comenzando un nuevo proyecto con `npx create-next-app@latest` y quiero integrar storybook automáticamente usando `npx storybook@next init` pero recibo el siguiente error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/code-frame'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\crcor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\eb8bf615e50a412a\node_modules\parse-json\index.js
- C:\Users\crcor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\eb8bf615e50a412a\node_modules\read-pkg\index.js
- C:\Users\crcor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\eb8bf615e50a412a\node_modules\@storybook\cli\node_modules\read-pkg-up\index.js   
- C:\Users\crcor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\eb8bf615e50a412a\node_modules\@storybook\cli\dist\generate.js
- C:\Users\crcor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\eb8bf615e50a412a\node_modules\@storybook\cli\bin\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\crcor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\eb8bf615e50a412a\node_modules\parse-json\index.js:5:28) 
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\crcor\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\eb8bf615e50a412a\\node_modules\\parse-json\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\crcor\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\eb8bf615e50a412a\\node_modules\\read-pkg\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\crcor\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\eb8bf615e50a412a\\node_modules\\@storybook\\cli\\node_modules\\read-pkg-up\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\crcor\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\eb8bf615e50a412a\\node_modules\\@storybook\\cli\\dist\\generate.js',   
    'C:\\Users\\crcor\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\eb8bf615e50a412a\\node_modules\\@storybook\\cli\\bin\\index.js'        
  ]
}

Node.js v18.14.2
```

Intenté instalar la dependencia `@babel/code-frame` pero el error persiste y no encontré nada al respecto.
Alguien puede ayudarme con esto? No sé qué más hacer...

Comment: Hola! Estás en el sitio en español. Por favor, traduce toda la pregunta yendo a [edit]

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, creí que debía pregunar en inglés!